# How to store the API keys of my clients in a secure way?

Tags: php, api, security, oauth, key

I am developing a SAAS service that allows my clients to connect third party emailing tools (eg MailChimp). I therefore ask to enter their API key associated with the desired service to allow certain actions to be performed automatically on their account.

For that I record in their database their key (s) API and the connection is done. But from a security point of view, if my database comes to be hacked despite all the predispositions taken in terms of security (prepared requests etc) ... These are all the API keys of my clients that are revealed and also email addresses of their own customers that can be retrieved, used, resold ... Because the tools I connect essentially allows to store contacts, organize and send emails.

So I wonder what is the best practice to allow my clients to use the API of their favorite tools without endangering the security of their own accounts and data of their customers (emails, etc). I am aware that currently launching my web application with this data in clear in database would be dangerous.

I thought of several solutions:

- Encrypt API keys in database, but I do not see how to test them (decryption) since it's not like a password?
- Store API keys on a different database hosted elsewhere, but the problem of encryption remains the same ... no?
- Use an OAuth stream: it seemed to be convenient, but all the services I want to connect via API do not offer this and I'm not even sure that this is really suitable for me.
- I intend to host my SAAS on Amazon web services, I saw that it was proposing a service called "KMS" Key managament storing but I do not know if it is really adapted once again to my problematic ...

If someone has already had to answer this problem, or knows how to solve it, I want to be enlightened on it!

Note: Sorry for my bad english, i'm French.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of the solutions you mentioned are somewhat valid and a combination is most likely the best answer. Your application needs access to these API keys so it's not really possible for a hacker to gain *full control* of your application and not gain control to the API keys. Full control being the key part - you can make it a lot harder to get to them.

#### Encryption

You would need encrypt them, not hash them, with something like AES. As you need to be able to decrypt them and use them in your requests towards the 3rd parties. This will help you protect against, eg. a database leak - if someone gets your database they would have to crack the encryption to get to them (as long as the encryption is properly implemented). The encryption/decryption key would of course have to be NOT in the database otherwise the whole thing has no point :)

#### Separation

Different database also makes sense - if someone dumps your main database they won't get to the API keys database and would have to get deeper into the application to access this database (ideally would be a completely separate DB server only accessible from your application).

Architecture of the solution matters too - you can have one server posing as a web-interface that is internet facing and that would talk to the backend server that is not internet facing over some limited (as much as possible) API to lower the attack surface. Only the backend server would then have access to the keys database and would perform the requests to the 3rd parties. Now an attacker has to jump through several servers to get even close to the keys.

---

Combining the above-mentioned will ensure one would have to obtain **full control** of your application (and all its parts) to get to the keys, the encryption key and bypass whatever other protection you might put in place.

Comment: Thank you very much for you advices and your help